# Determine the divisor so that the quotient is less than 6,000.

Tags: divisibility

**Determine the divisor so that the quotient is always less than 6,000.  The dividend may be any number less than, greater than or equal to 6,000.**

I'm looking for a formula to help speed up a process at work.  I can code this out in long hand using if/then statements (sample below), but I'm wondering if there are any creative math folk that could simplify this.  I don't need it coded, I can do that myself if someone provides me a better logic than what I have.

Let's I have these dividends:  5000,13000,28000 (100000 max).  I want their quotient to be less than 6000.  In other words, I want to know the divisor

```
if 6000 >= x > 6000, result=1
elif 12000 >= x > 6000, result=2
elif 18000 >= x > 6000, result=3
elif 24000 >= x > 6000, result=4
elif 30000 >= x > 6000, result=5
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the smallest divisor that is acceptable.  Given $n$ the result is $\lfloor\frac n{6000}\rfloor$.  If you want the quotient strictly below $6000$ you need to subtract $1$ if $n$ is an exact multiple of $6000$

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called integer division.  How you code it depends on what language you are using.  For example, in python 3 you would write `x//6000`.  In the C-type languages you would write `x/6000`, assuming x is an integer variable.